# Unable to find TeamCity 9.1.x data directory

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

This is really weird.

I am trying a clean Teamcity 9.1.1 install but the Data Directory is nowhere to be found.

- if I access the Global Settings tab under Administration, it lists "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.BuildServer" - a folder that doesn't exist.
- if I try to browse to that folder, it shows me a range of files; uploading a specific file there instead uploads it to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile.BuildServer.
- there is no teamcity-startup.properties file anywhere - I am unable to customize the location of the data directory.
- when I restore a backup, the backup files are instead restored to C:\Users\[user name]\.BuildServer rather than in the correct data directory.

Does anyone has any suggestions on how to regain control of the situation? How can I tell TeamCity which data folder to use?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the situation by:

- stopping TC services;
- creating a teamcity-startup.properties in [install folder]\conf with the following content:

  teamcity.data.path=D:\\[install folder]\\config
- restarting TC services;
- restoring my backup.

This restored the 9.1.1 install as well as stabilizing the location of the data directory. After this  was done, the subsequent installation of 9.1.7 prompted me to uninstall 9.1.1 first (which it hadn’t done the first time around) and the upgrade succeeded.

I believe the system was already compromised at the beginning, unknown to me, due to the data folder being all over the place. Once that was resolved, everything else fell into place.